# Salvar último valor digitado em variável parametrizada

Tags: jenkins

Tenho um job parametrizado no jenkins, no caso a variável é o número de uma versão, ou de um patch. Que toda vez que vou fazer build a digito.

Gostaria de **salvar o último valor digitado na variável**, de forma que eu não precise verificar qual foi a último valor informado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O plugin [Persistent Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/persistent-parameter) que resolve o problema.

Basta adicionar tipo do parâmetro como "Persistent String Parameter:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim o valor digitado no parâmetro será retirado da compilação anterior (se houver). E ainda tem a opção de salvar se o build tiver sucesso.